# Messy logs in multi - threaded java application using log4j

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, log4j

I've enabled log4j logging for a multi-threaded application which makes the log file hard to analyse.

Log file looks like

```
2019-10-02 07:49:55:DEBUG  :Main: Start of the call
2019-10-02 07:49:55:DEBUG  :pool-1-thread-4: Running in pool-1-thread-4
2019-10-02 07:49:55:DEBUG  :pool-1-thread-2: Running in pool-1-thread-2
2019-10-02 07:49:55:DEBUG  :pool-1-thread-4: Running in pool-1-thread-4
```

Can we group the logs based on the thread id either while logging or atleast after parsing the log file ?

Answer (score 0):

CMD: [`sort /+28 log`](https://ss64.com/nt/sort.html)

Bash: [`sort -k 3,3 -k 1,2 log`](https://ss64.com/bash/sort.html)